# How to fix Image on top of text with css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am unsure on how to fix this..

http://jsfiddle.net/PaDvr/

I'd like the image to be place before the text, not on top of it.

the html:

```
<div id="photo">
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://cdn.androidpolice.com/wp-content/themes/ap1/images/android1.png">
</div>
<div id="text" class="media-body">
    lorem ipsum bla blah...
    </div>​
```

the css:

```
#photo{
    border: 1px solid black;
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 200px;
    min-width: 266px;
    min-height: 286px;
    position: relative;
    left: 32%;
    top: 23px;
}​
```

what causes the image to be on top of the text?

Comment: Do you want the text below the image or do you want the image behind the text?

Comment: do you want something like http://jsfiddle.net/XzbvW/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here. The first is that your max and min width and height settings. The max height of the div should be at least as tall as the image, and taller than the min-height. [See it here](http://jsfiddle.net/AaUYL/)

```
#photo {
  ...
  max-height: 404px;
}
```

The second is that your `relative` positioning removes it from the regular document flow. The nature of `relative` positioning is such that moving it down 23px moves it 23px over whatever happens to be beneath it. One way to offset this would be adding a margin-bottom to the image that is equal to your relative offset. [View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KFxXt/)

```
#photo {
  position: relative;
  left: 32%;
  top: 23px;
  margin-bottom: 23px;
}
```

Though if you're just trying to move the image down and over, I'd just use margins instead of relative positioning. [View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4bvL/)

```
#photo{
  ...
  margin-left: 32%;
  margin-top: 23px;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Your  `max-height: 200px;` and `top: 23px;` is causing this issue. If you remove it then it doesn't overlap. http://jsfiddle.net/PaDvr/3/

Answer (score 1):

Remove `max-height: 200px;` from your CSS and add

```
.​media-body {
    margin-top: 23px;  
}​
```

You need to take into account the top: 23px in your #photo and this can be done by setting your .media-body margin-top: 23px;

Answer (score 0):

Because top:xx push relative objects, add

```
margin-bottom:23px
```

ej:

```
#photo{

    border: 1px solid black;

    max-width: 100px;

    max-height: 200px;

    min-width: 266px;

    min-height: 286px;

    position: relative;

    left: 32%;

    top: 23px;

    margin-bottom:23px

}    ​
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/PaDvr/5/

Answer (score 0):

The above answers solve the issue if you want to show the full size image.

However, if your intention was to scale down the image to max 100px wide and confine it to the photo div, the root cause is that by default bootstrap CSS is applying max-width:100% to the image and this is throwing the resizing off.

Solution is to add a new class

```
#photo img{
max-width:100px;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/PaDvr/28/

Then you can use the suggestions above to resize the photo div as required